# Element is working for the local but not for the jenkins in selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver

There is tool tip scenario it is working fine in my local but getting unable to locate element in jenkins. I have given wait and also using isDisplayed() method to get the element .I have to verify tool tip functionality is there any other way to verify?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not about Jenkins and local. Maybe in Jenkins, it's taking a long time to display the element. One thing you can do is, running your script on the machine where Jenkins is located, I mean as you running locally but the machine will be where Jenkins is located. Let me know, what you get.